# How to programmatically detect command keybinding (shortcut) conflict

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, visual-studio-sdk

I have command shortcut in extension which is working well in `VS2012` and `VS2015`. But starting from `VS2017` it doesn't work. Now VS has its own command shortcut with such keys combination. Commands have different scope VS - `Text Editor` and my command for `TSQL-Editor`. Strange but more specific scope (`TSQL-Editor`) shortcut doesn't work.

I have implemented [Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleCommandTarget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.ole.interop.iolecommandtarget?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) but `QueryStatus` doesn't call when I'm trying to execute my command.

There should be some mechanism because for example ReSharper can detect such conflicts

[image]

How to handle keybinding conflicts?

Comment: Haven't found the way to detect command keybinding. But according to the official document: `Many keyboard shortcuts are already used in Visual Studio. You should not assign the same shortcut to more than one command because duplicate bindings are hard to detect and may also cause unpredictable results. Therefore, it is a good idea to verify the availability of a shortcut before you assign it.` . So maybe you can [identify this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/identifying-and-customizing-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) before you customize the shortcuts.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Thanks. Yes we check every time adding new shortcuts. But VS also growing up and adding new shortcuts in new versions :) Why more specific scope `TSQL-Editor` doesn't have higher priority then `Text Editor`?

Comment: T-SQL editor is for Microsoft-SQL Server Data Tools, do you mean when you're using this editor, the shortcut does not work but the one for Text Editor does?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Yes. In `sql` file (`TSQL-Editor` scope) doesn't work shortcut for this scope but work for `Text Editor`. The same is for `cs` file. For example for  `Edit.InsertTab` I assigned `Ctrl+Shift+L` in `CSharp Editor` scope. Also this shortcut is `Edit.LineDelete` in `Text Editor`. In `cs` file it doesn't add tabs but it deletes lines.

Comment: After my test, the Text Editor's priority is exactly higher than any other editor. I test it in both VS2015 and VS2017. I'm still researching this settings, not sure it's by design or an issue, any update I will share here. And for the API in VS2017 sdk to check the keybinding conflict, maybe you can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.command.collection?view=visualstudiosdk-2017).

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Hello. Have you found any information?